# PHP Going through array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a $search_array like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => book
            [search] => steve
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => book
            [search] => john
        )


foreach ($search_array as $s) {

    $arrayid = //???????
    $searchtype = $s['type'];
    $search = urlencode($s['search']);

getResult($arrayid);

}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the array number.  So for the first result i need $arrayid to be 1.  How do I reference that in the foreach loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a foreach with "$key => $value"

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => book
            [search] => steve
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => book
            [search] => john
        )

foreach ($search_array as $key => $s) {

    $arrayid = $key
    $searchtype = $s['type'];
    $search = urlencode($s['search']);

getResult($arrayid);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `$arrayid =>` in your foreach loop declaration will auto-assign `$arrayid` with the current array index.

```
foreach ($search_array as $arrayid => $s) {
  // ...
  getResult($arrayid);
}
```

See [`foreach` on PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($search_array as $arrayid => $s) {
```

Please read [PHP documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) before asking such basic questions

Comment: @vpets a very simple search would have helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you could retrieve data from a Php array. It will retrieve all entries from array $value and their key $key.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  // $key is the array index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($search_array as $arrayid => $s) {
    // your code here
}
```